# why is the query so slow with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for email message system.

That is :

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE folder_id = ? AND messageID IS NULL ORDER BY  `uid` DESC
```

And the index I added are

```
PRIMARY (folder_id, uid)
folder_id_msgid (folder_id, messageID, uid)
messageID (messageID)
```

But it's still very slow.

I don't know if I created the wrong keys, or should not use 'messageID IS NULL'  for query.

If 'messageID IS NULL' should not be used. Then how can I perform the same function.

explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      message      ref    PRIMARY,messageID,folder_id_arrival,folder_id_msgi...   folder_id_msgid     772     const,const     1   Using where
```

Comment: what does `explain select ...` shows ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: A full table scan ;)

Comment: ah `ORDER BY  uid` so order by a key which is not a part of the where `The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY: ` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: What is the number of rows in this table?

Comment: 8,644,269 rows, and when the db is accessed by multi-threads(same query), each query can spend more than 1000s

Comment: Your query has used an index (and the one I would expect it to use), but slightly concerned that the key length of that index is 772, when I would expect it to just be the length of 3 integer fields. To me that suggests that folder_id, messageid and uid are stored in large varchar fields rather than integer fields.

Answer (score 2):

None of your indexes matches where criteria:

```
folder_id + messageId
```

Your indexes are for criterias:

```
folder_id + uid
folder_id + messageId + uid
messageIID
```

Having an additional index for either

```
folder_id + messageID
```

or

```
folder_id only
```

should help

Comment: The 2nd index should cover it. MySQL can just ignore the last column of the index that isn't required by the select (but is by the ORDER clause).